# How can we change the code to select the words in the table which are started with the letter "O"

Tags: javascript, html

Can you help me to change the next code in the following way? We need to select the words in the table which are started with the letter "O". Now we have that it is selected the words which have the length like 3.

```
var array_word = ['рама','облако','Рим','орел','крик','олень','титр','тигр','олово'];
var array_symbol = ['т','и','р'];

function getRandom(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
}

function showTable(count_rows, count_cols) {
    var htmlcode = '';
    ROWS_SIZE = count_rows;
    COLS_SIZE = count_cols;
    for (var rows = 0; rows < count_rows; rows++) {
        htmlcode += '<tr>\n';
        for (var cols = 0; cols < count_cols; cols++) {
            htmlcode += '<td id="td' + rows + cols + '">' + array_word[getRandom(0,array_word.length-1)] + '</td>'
        }
        htmlcode += '</tr>\n';
    }
    document.getElementById("main_table").innerHTML = htmlcode;
}

function toMark() {                    
    for (var rows = 0; rows < ROWS_SIZE; rows++) {
        for (var cols = 0; cols < COLS_SIZE; cols++) {
            if (checkWord(document.getElementById("main_table").rows[rows].cells[cols].innerHTML)) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("td" + rows + cols);
                elem.setAttribute("class","selected");
            }
        }
    }
}

function checkWord(word) {
    if (word.length == 3) {
         return true;
            } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="showTable(10,10)">
<div align="center">
    <table id="main_table">
    </table>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Выделить" onclick="toMark()">
    <input type="button" value="Генерировать" onclick="showTable(10,10)">
</div>
```

Comment: So check the first letter if it is `O`. Plenty of ways to do it: substr, substring, charAt, regExp, etc...

Comment: I.E. function check(x) { return x.substring(0,1) === "O"; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `checkWord` function like below...

```
function checkWord(word) {
    if (word[0].toLowerCase() == 'o') {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I had with your code is the different type set for the language. Your `о` differs from the latin `o`.

```js
var array_word = ['рама','облако','Рим','орел','крик','олень','титр','тигр','олово'];
var array_symbol = ['т','и','р'];
 
function getRandom(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min;
}
 
function showTable(count_rows, count_cols) {
    var htmlcode = '';
    ROWS_SIZE = count_rows;
    COLS_SIZE = count_cols;
    for (var rows = 0; rows < count_rows; rows++) {
        htmlcode += '<tr>\n';
        for (var cols = 0; cols < count_cols; cols++) {
            htmlcode += '<td id="td' + rows + cols + '">' + array_word[getRandom(0,array_word.length-1)] + '</td>'
        }
        htmlcode += '</tr>\n';
    }
    document.getElementById("main_table").innerHTML = htmlcode;
}
 
function toMark() {                    
    for (var rows = 0; rows < ROWS_SIZE; rows++) {
        for (var cols = 0; cols < COLS_SIZE; cols++) {
            if (checkWord(document.getElementById("main_table").rows[rows].cells[cols].innerHTML)) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("td" + rows + cols);
                elem.setAttribute("class","selected");
            }
        }
    }
}
 
function checkWord(word) {
    return word[0].toLowerCase() === 'о';
}
```

```html
<style>
    .selected { background-color: #ffff00; }
</style>
<body onload="showTable(10,10)">
<div align="center">
    <table id="main_table">
    </table>
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Выделить" onclick="toMark()">
    <input type="button" value="Генерировать" onclick="showTable(10,10)">
</div>
```